# Button in ReactJS calls the function only after the second click, no effect after the first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple app for visualization of sorting algorithms in ReactJS.
Here is my function:

```
const [HeightsArray, setHeightsArray] = useState([]);
const [Array, setArray] = useState(ArrayList(HeightsArray));
  
  const randomize = ()=>{
    const randomList = RandomHeightsList(ArrayLength);
    setHeightsArray(randomList);
    setArray(ArrayList(HeightsArray));
}
```

The RandomHeightsList function simply returns an array of random numbers.

```
const RandomHeightList = (ArrayLength)=>{
    let randomHeightsArray = [];
    while (randomHeightsArray.length<ArrayLength){
        let randomHeight = Math.round(Math.random()*350);
        randomHeightsArray.push(randomHeight);
    }
    return randomHeightsArray;
```

The ArrayList function creates an array of elements (divs) where each element has the corresponding height from a given array of heights as shown below:

```
const ArrayList = (heightsArray) => {
    let array = [];
    for (let i=0; i<heightsArray.length; i++){
        array.push(ArrayElement(heightsArray[i]));
    }
    return (
        <div className="array-list">
            {array}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Finally, Array Element is just a div with some height.

```
const ArrayElement = (height) => {
    const baseTop = 300;
    let top = baseTop-height;
    let styleObject = {height: height, top: top};
    return (
        <div className="array-element" style={styleObject}>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now here is my simple button:

```
<button className="randomize-button" onClick={randomize}>Randomize</button>
```

When I click the button the first time, nothing happens, the array does not get randomized. However, after that it works well. If I click the button the second time it gets randomized. If I click it a third time it gets randomized again as it should. It has no effect the first time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting ArrayList from and what does it do? Also, how are you displaying the output?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I edited the question to provide some more specification. The output is displayed as one single row of divs on an html page where each div has some height that corresponds to ArrayElement component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with these lines in your `randomize` function:

```
setHeightsArray(randomList);
setArray(ArrayList(HeightsArray));
```

You are setting the value of HeightsArray and using it right away, but it won't get updated until next render.
So you need to change the second line to:

```
setArray(ArrayList(randomList));
```